# What are the possible levels of nested quotes in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string, escaping

I am trying to directly write a Javascript variable assignment code on a ASP.NET web page.

```
Response.Write("<script>itHtml = '");
Response.Write("<div id=\"pop_ctrl\">Select</div><ul id=\"demo_ul\">");
foreach (Article a in arts)
{
    Response.Write("<li class=\"demo_li\"><a onclick=\"ShowArticleCard(" + a.Id + ",\'" + a.User + "\',\'" + a.DateString + "\'); return false\"><div>" + it.User + "</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div>" + it.Title + "</div></a></li>");
}
Response.Write("</ul>");
Response.Write("';</script>");
```

Anchor tag in this markup executes a function `ShowArticleCard()` on click. This function accepts one `int` and two `string` parameters. When I am trying to add a C# string variable in place of string parameters, it replaces them like a JavaScript keyword. I tried using  `'`,`\'` and `\"`, but error persists. So, are there any levels of nested quotes we can use? If not how can I resolve this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to escape single quotes at all, what error do you get if you just use the single quote?

Comment: Error I get is `missing ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way of doing this. I don't know why it didn't came in my mind before.

I enclosed JavaScript function's string parameters with `\\'`. Like this:

```
ShowArticleCard(" + a.Id + ",\\'" + a.User + "\\',\\'" + a.DateString + "\\');
```

So that the resultant code will be:

```
ShowArticleCard(someid,\'someUser\',\'someDateString\');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the actual value (parameter) in the quotes, like this,

```
onclick=\"ShowArticleCard(" + a.Id + ",'" + 
          a.User + "','" + a.DateString + "'); // Remaining code
```

**Changed**

I have removed the single quotes from the int type param, and removed the escape slash from the string types. They can be simply put as, `'`. Now when the code would run, it would be considered as a string. Otherwise (if the value is numeric) then ignore these quotes and enter them as they are. Only string-type data requires to be wrapped in either `'` or `"`. *In JavaScript they are same*. In **C#**, `'` and `"` have different meanings, **you know that well**.

***Tip***: Also, if you are writing something for client-side rendering, like in ASP.NET, you can easily write it as,

```
string.Format("<a href='{0}' onclick='func({1})'>My Link</a>",
               hyperlink, param);
```

This would be rendered as you want it to be. :) The single quotes would be converted to double quotes once rendered in your browser. **Or** you can use `@` before the string, and write `"` inside the string without having to escape them.

Comment: If I do that, the code after first `'` will be considered as outside. Because main string in starting with `'` at `itHtml='`.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva, I am sorry for late reply. See my answer now. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Afzaal but I figured out a simple way of doing it. Check my answer. I didn't checked your code but +1 to you for the alternative way using `string.Format()`. I don't know why I am forgetting these basic C# operations. :P